# Mock a method of the subject under test in Moq?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I want to test method A of my class, but without calling the actual method B which is normally called by A. That's because B has a lot of external interactions I don't want to test for now.

I could create mocks for all the services called by B, but that's quite some work. I'd rather just mock B and make it return sample data.

Is that possible to do with Moq framework?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is, with a catch!
You have to make sure method `B` is virtual and can be overriden.

Then, set the mock to call the base methods whenever a setup is not provided. Then you setup `B`, but don't setup `A`. Because `A` was not setup, the actual implementation will be called.

```
var myClassMock = new Mock<MyClass>();
myClassMock.Setup(x => x.B()); //mock B

myClassMock.CallBase = true;

MyClass obj = myClassMock.Object;
obj.A(); // will call the actual implementation
obj.B(); // will call the mock implementation
```

Behinds the scenes, Moq will dynamically create a class that extends `MyClass` and overrides `B`.

Comment: Exactly, and it will be easiest if the `virtual` method `B` is either `protected internal` or `public`.

Comment: Question: What does the line CallBase = true; do?

Comment: @Hace If I recall correctly, it tells the mock object to call the methods defined in `MyClass`, unless an explicit setup is provided. If you did not call `CallBase = true`, then Moq would call a fake implementation of every virtual method, regardless of whether an explicit setup had been provided.

Comment: Hi, @dcastro Thanks I found out the CallBase line is indeed necessary to ensure the method is being called, thanks

Comment: `protected internal virtual` does not show up on the mock setup?

Comment: @dcastro - apparently, this does not seems to be working for me. If i try to create a mock of my concrete class using MyClass obj = myClassMock.Object - it throws an exception "the class does not supports paramterless constructor"  if I use the interface to create the mock, the method 'A' itself does not gets called 
any thoughts on what i might be doing wrong ?

Comment: This worked for me for some things, but didn't work for SetupGet - neither in interface nor with the class.