# Get Mock with AutoMock.Create<>()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofac, automoq

I am using the [AutoMock](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/moq.html) integration of [Autofaq](http://autofac.org/) and [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)

Is there a way to get a mock from `AutoMock.Create<Service>()`?

The reason I want this, is to mock some methods of the class under test (Service) like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460834/mock-a-method-of-the-subject-under-test-in-moq/21460952#21460952) and also keep the automatic creation of mock dependencies.

Comment: Could you include code sample ? I'm not sure to understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
var mock = Mock.Get(myMockedService);
mock.Setup(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but in case it could help someone else, if you want to get a mock of your service, you should use AutoMock.Mock(), since AutoMock.Create() returns a "real" instance of your service.

You can see the difference between return types in the doc.
Create: https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/93EE0136.htm
Mock: https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/66E87E8B.htm