# Mock a method of class under test with Moq & AutoMock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, autofac

I've been reading around and I can't seem to find a case that matches the behavior I want with Moq.
I want to mock a specific method (which is interfacing with an external API) of a class that I want to test. The problem is that, as I understand it, once the class is `.Create<T>`, you cannot `.Setup()...` any method on it.

Here is an example:

```
public class ClassA
{
   public void ConfigureExpansion()
   {
         var classB = new ClassB();

         var data = GetExternalData(); // I want to mock this
         //data is used in the code

         classB.TaskB(data); // I want to mock this
   }

   public string GetExternalData()
   {
         return data...
   }
}

public class ClassB
{
   public void TaskB(String myData)
   {
         //Does some work
   }
}
```

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
   {
      mock.Mock<IClassB>().Setup(x => x.TaskB(It.IsAny<string>()));
                     

      var cls = mock.Create<ClassA>();
      cls.Setup(x => x.GetExternalData(It.IsAny<string>())).Return("MyData");   // <--- This is not valid, but represents what I am trying to do.

      //act
      cls.ConfigureExpansion();

      mock.Mock<IClassB>().Verify(x => x.TaskB(), Times.Once);
   }
}
```

I tried to set up a mock for the interface of my class under test, but the `cls` won't call it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
   {
      mock.Mock<IClassA>().Setup(x => x.GetExternalData(It.IsAny<string>())).Return("MyData"); //<--- Mocking the method here is not detected by the cls below

      mock.Mock<IClassB>().Setup(x => x.TaskB(It.IsAny<string>()));             

      var cls = mock.Create<ClassA>();

      //act
      cls.ConfigureExpansion();

      mock.Mock<IClassB>().Verify(x => x.TaskB(), Times.Once);
   }
}
```

I've also tried instantiating my class-under-test and when I do it like this, it doesn't take the mocks (ClassB) into consideration:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
   {
      mock.Mock<IClassA>().Setup(x => x.GetExternalData(It.IsAny<string>())).Return("MyData"); //<--- Mocking the method here is not detected by the cls below

      mock.Mock<IClassB>().Setup(x => x.TaskB(It.IsAny<string>()));             

      var cls = new ClassA();

      //act
      cls.ConfigureExpansion();

      mock.Mock<IClassB>().Verify(x => x.TaskB(), Times.Once);
   }
}
```

I would really appreciate any insights about this,
Thank you

Comment: If `cls` (or `ClassA`) is your class-under-test, then you should create using its constructor, not a mock version of it. And what is the relation between `IClassB` with `ClassA`? Is it a dependency for `ClassA`?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the purpose of .Create then. I thought this was how you were supposed to instantiate your class-under-test.
About the IClassB and ClassA, the relation would be something along the line of a database interface class, which contains all the queries, which I want to mock in this case. ClassA leverages ClassB to get data.

Comment: @Phyziik Could you please extend your question with the to be tested code as well? I'm also not even sure which line of your test should be considered as the Act phase. And what do you want to assess?

Comment: @PeterCsala You are completely right, my question was lacking code context. I overhauled the code portions of my question. Hopefully, it's clearer. Sorry.

Comment: @Phyziik Thanks for sharing that piece of code as well. The thing is you can't mock `classB` like this. `ClassA` should receive a `IClassB` instance in its constructor to be able to mock it. Also if you want to mock `GetExternalData` then you should done it by using the `CallBase` feature of the mock. If you wish I can leave a post to explain both concepts in a bit more detail

Comment: @PeterCsala I looked into Callbase, but I didn't seem to work either. Could you give me an example that you thing would allow me to mock GetExternalData with CallBase? Thank you

Comment: @Phyziik Here is a [sample how to use Callbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460834/mock-a-method-of-the-subject-under-test-in-moq)

Comment: @popsiporkkanaa *"If cls ... is your class-under-test, then you should create using its constructor ..."* Why do you say that? If you use `new ClassA`, then the object has NO mocked dependencies. Defeating the primary purpose of mocking, afaik. See `var sut = mock.Create<SystemUnderTest>();` in second code snippet of [autofac moq doc](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/moq.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach for your problem. If you want to test `ConfigureExpansion` of `ClassA`, you have to mock the dependencies used in that method, which is `ClassB`. You cannot mock `GetExternalData` of `ClassA` because `ClassA` is the class under test now. You may have to refactor your classes in a way so that there is a `ClassUnderTest` which creates both instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` using dependency injection. Then, you can use Moq to mock the interfaces `IClassA` and `IClassB` to test the `ConfigureExpansion`.

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private readonly IClassA _classA;
    private readonly IClassB _classB;

    public ClassUnderTest(IClassA classA, IClassB classB)
    {
        this._classA = classA;
        this._classB = classB;
    }

    public void ConfigureExpansion()
    {
        var data = this._classA.GetExternalData();
        this._classB.TaskB(data);
    }
}


public interface IClassA
{
    string GetExternalData();
}

public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public string GetExternalData()
    {
        return "some data";
    }
}

public interface IClassB
{
    void TaskB(string myData);
}

public class ClassB : IClassB
{
    public void TaskB(string myData)
    {
        //Does some work
    }
}
```

The test method can be:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
        {
            var mockClassA = mock.Mock<IClassA>();
            var mockClassB = mock.Mock<IClassB>();
            mockClassA.Setup(x => x.GetExternalData()).Returns("MyData");

            var cls = new ClassUnderTest(mockClassA.Object, mockClassB.Object);

            //act
            cls.ConfigureExpansion();

           mockClassB.Verify(x => x.TaskB(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted but my best guess is that it is because you have entirely ignored AutoMock. But this is just an educated guess.

Comment: @PeterCsala I still used AutoMock in the test method example as the OP used.

Comment: You have handcrafted the System Under Test (`cls` variable in this case), not by calling the `mock.Create<ClassUnderTest>()`

Comment: I see your point about the refactoring. I just feel like I will probably encounter this issue more often than not, so I'm trying to figure out a way to handle that scenario. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Adding to @PeterCsala's comment: `var cls = new ClassUnderTest(mockClassA.Object, mockClassB.Object);` doesn't use dependency injection. That's an ..unusual.. use of `Autofac`. My understanding is that, given a DI framework, by the time you get to a statement that creates the test object, you should be able to simply do `var cls = mock.Create<ClassUnderTest>();`. Preceding statements would set it up so that the needed dependencies `IClassA` and `IClassB` get created automatically as mock objects. (But who knows - perhaps this technique is useful in some advanced situation.)