# Autofac.Extras.Moq - response from mocked Login does not contain expected value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.forms, mocking, autofac

I want to make unit tests in my app. I use NUNIT, and the following libraries :

- Autofac.Extras.Moq
- AutoFixture

I followed this samples but it doesn't work :

- http://makanda.io/unit-testing-xamarin-forms-view-model/
- [Mock a method of class under test with Moq & AutoMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665858/mock-a-method-of-class-under-test-with-moq-automock)

Here is my test :

```cs
private Fixture _fixture;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
   _fixture = new Fixture();
}

[Test]
public void Login_Success()
{
   using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
   {
      var infosLogin = _fixture.Create<LoginRequest>();
      var loginResponse = _fixture.Create<LoginResponse>();

      var userService = mock.Mock<IUserService>();
      userService
         .Setup(user => user.Login(infosLogin))
         .Returns(Task.FromResult(loginResponse));

      var viewModel = new MainPageViewModel(new ContentPage(), userService.Object);

      viewModel.Login = infosLogin.Username;
      viewModel.Password = infosLogin.Password;
      viewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(null);
   }
}
```

My view

```cs
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel(this, new UserServiceImpl());
}
```

My ViewModel

```cs
public MainPageViewModel(Page page, IUserService userService)
{
   _page = page;
   _userService = userService;

   Login = "";
   Password = "";
}

public Command LoginCommand
{
   get
   {
      return new Command(async () =>
      {
         Console.WriteLine("step 1...");

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Login) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
         {
            Console.WriteLine("step 2...");
            var infos = new LoginRequest() { Username = "Wyllis", Password = "test" };
            LoginResponse response = await _userService.Login(infos);
            Console.WriteLine("step 3...");
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Age = response.Age; // Got error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
         }
      });
   }
}
```

LoginResponse model

```cs
public class LoginResponse
{
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

`Age = response.Age;`, I Got error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object, can you explain what is wrong ?

Comment: 1) Add to question, definition of `LoginResponse`. 2) Put breakpoint on `Console.WriteLine(response);`. Examine `response` in Locals pane. Is it the same as `var loginResponse`? If so, then the mock test did what you told it to do.

Comment: When I put breakpoints on my ViewModel and I execute tests breakpoints are not triggered.

Comment: Is it printing out messages "step 1...", etc?

Comment: what is in the constructor of `MainPageViewModel`?  And why are you passing a page reference to your VM?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes it is, all are printed excepted `Console.WriteLine(response);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, `new LoginRequest(...)` from my viewmodel and my tests are same BUT the hashcode (memory address) is different, so my test fail because my param is not the same object with the same memory than viewmodel

here is my new test and my view model

ViewModel

```cs
public Command LoginCommand
{
   get
   {
      return new Command(async () =>
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Login) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
         {
            var infos = new LoginRequest() { Username = Login, Password = Password };
            LoginResponse response = await _userService.Login(infos);

            Age = response.Age;
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Test

```cs
private Mock<IUserService> _userService;
private MainPageViewModel _viewModel;
private Fixture _fixture;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
            using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
            {
                _userService = mock.Mock<IUserService>();
            }
            _fixture = new Fixture();
        }

        private MainPageViewModel CreateInstance()
        {
            return new MainPageViewModel(_userService.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test_Constructor()
        {
            using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
            {
                var viewModel = mock.Create<MainPageViewModel>();

                viewModel.Login.Equals("");
                viewModel.Password.Equals("");
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Login_Success()
        {
            var user = _fixture.Create<LoginResponse>();

            _viewModel = CreateInstance();
            _viewModel.Login = "test";
            _viewModel.Password = "test";

            _userService
                .Setup(s => s.Login(It.IsAny<LoginRequest>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(user))
                .Verifiable();

            _viewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(null);

            _userService.Verify();

            Assert.AreEqual(_viewModel.Age, user.Age);
        }
```